# Attempted import error: 'Icon' is not exported from 'antd'

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, antd

I have created a react app using 'create-react-app' and in one of my project files, i'm using the following import statement;

`import { Icon } from 'antd'`,

and receiving the following error:

```
Attempted import error: 'Icon' is not exported from 'antd'.
```

not sure what the issue is. please help.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

On upgrading the version of Ant Design to v4, one of the major breaking changes have been that `Icon` is no longer exported from `antd` package.

Also instead of having string based icon references like:

```
// Before
<Icon type="smile" />
```

In v4:

```
import { SmileOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';

<SmileOutlined />
```

There is still an `Icon` export, but that is from the package `@ant-design/icons` instead of just `antd`. This `Icon` export can be used for adding custom icons.

[Docs](https://ant.design/components/icon/) [Changelog](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/21656)

Comment: i've installed the ant design package using "npm i -D antd", and this import statement, "import { Icon } from '@ant-design/icons' is not working. should i remove and install the package with a different command ? how should i go about it ?

Comment: Yes, thank you, your solution worked, i had to separately do `npm i -D @ant-design/icons` and then had to import each icon separately. thank you for your help bro.

Comment: `-D` is for installing a developer dependency, unless you intend to add it as a library, you don't require it

Comment: I was trying to use a Icon from Antd while following an tutorial. Worked for me when I imported `LoadingOutlined` instead of `Icon`.

Thanks for pointing out the direction!

Answer (score 18):

In v4, the icons are a default export, so do

```
import Icon from '@ant-design/icons';
```

instead of

```
import {Icon} from 'antd';
```

You might also need to do `npm install @ant-design/icons --save-dev`

Comment: why --save-dev instead of just --save, this is needed in prod code as well isn't it instead of just in dev env ?

Comment: Depends on your build scripts - if scripts are compiled and build in dev mode, and deployed, you wont be using npm in production. If you use some es6 modules on production or build the bundles in production server - maybe —save is the right way. But depends on your setup.

Answer (score 6):

Your import is wrong.

Check ant documentation:
https://ant.design/components/icon/

Are you using v4?

`import Icon from '@ant-design/icons';`

Comment: I am using v4 but i've installed ant design using "npm i -D antd", and i've tried this import statement and it doesn't work. how should i go about it ?

Comment: Did you install also `https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ant-design/icons`?

Comment: no i did not, however i am using ant-design version: 4.0.2, so it should come packaged inside already. is that not the case ? @JaLe

Comment: Yes, you are right. Are you trying to use some icon, or what?

Comment: Yes, 2 actually. one for the user `<Icon type="user" style={{ color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.25)' }} />`and one for the password `<Icon type="lock" style={{ color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.25)' }} />` also i've tried `npm i -D @ant-design/icons` but it still gives the same error.

Comment: @MushoodHanif It is wrong. In ant version 4. you should use `import { SmileOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';` -> `<SmileOutlined style={{ color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.25)' }} />`

Comment: I've found the solution, will be sharing it. thanks for your help bro.

Answer (score 2):

i added '@ant-design/compatible' it works for me

```
yarn add @ant-design/compatible --save-dev
```

Answer (score -7):

I resolved this by running npm install -g, probably not the best approach; will review and refactor if needed.

Comment: That does not properly address the issue